# click, getElementByClassName etc with for() not working

Tags: javascript

I am a Javascript beginner and am trying to solve a problem here. I don't find the mistake.

I try that the ID and the class variants work. The click and the message does not work.

**java script**

```js
let click = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');

let messageAllClass = document.querySelectorAll('.messageAllClass');
let messageClass = document.getElementByClassName('messageClass');
let messeageIDuniq = document.getElementById('messageID');

let messageTxtAllClass = "hallo from AllClass";
let messageTxtClass = "hallo from Class";
let messageTxtIDuniq = "hallo from ID, i am unique :-)";

let deleted = "deleted";
let i;
let cls = clicks.length;

//messageAllClass.innerHTML = messAllClass.textContent + messageTxtAllClass;
//messageClass.innerHTML = messageClass.textContent + messageTxtClass;
messeageIDuniq.innerHTML = messeageIDuniq.textContent + messageTxtIDuniq;

for(let i = 0; i < messageAllClass.length; i++) {
    messageAllClass[i].innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('.messageAllClass');
}

for(let i = 0; i < messageClass.length; i++) {
    messageClass[i].innerHTML = document.getElementByClassName('messageClass');
}

for (let i = 0; i < cls; i++) {
  click[i].onclick = function () {
    messageAllClass.innerHTML = "null";
    messageClass.innerHTML = "null";
    messeageIDuniq.innerHTML = deleted;
    alert("all messages deleted!");
  }
}
```

**html**

```html
<h1>On one side</h1>

<div class="main">
  <h3>Message:</h3>
  <div class="messageAllClass"></div>
  <div class="messageClass"></div>
  <div id="messageID"></div>
</div>

<div class="panel">
  <h3>Panel:</h3>
  <div class="messageAllClass"></div>
  <div class="messageClass"></div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="trigger">Delete all messages</button>
```

> **[saved on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cemfirat/pjanqsow/latest/)**

Comment: Replace `let cls = clicks.length;` with `let cls = click.length;`, I guess you made a typo!

Comment: First of all getElementsByClassName not getElementByClassName, Elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make some mistakes, as you can see in comment. So I try fixed and some refactoring your code.

```
let clicks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.trigger'));

let messageAllClass = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.messageAllClass'));
let messageClass = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('messageClass'));
let messeageIDuniq = document.getElementById('messageID');

let messageTxtAllClass = "hallo from AllClass";
let messageTxtClass = "hallo from Class";
let messageTxtIDuniq = "hallo from ID, i am unique :-)";

let deleted = "deleted";

messeageIDuniq.innerHTML = messeageIDuniq.textContent + messageTxtIDuniq;
messageAllClass.forEach(i=>i.innerHTML = messageTxtAllClass)
messageClass.forEach(i=>i.innerHTML = messageTxtClass)

const onDelete = function() {
  messageAllClass.forEach(i=>i.innerHTML = deleted)
  messageClass.forEach(i=>i.innerHTML = deleted)
  messeageIDuniq.innerHTML = deleted;
  alert("all messages deleted!");
}

clicks.forEach(b=>b.onclick = onDelete)
```

See in playground, I hope this helps you: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/f6mrx10c/10/#&togetherjs=dBkaxLHuzC

Comment: Thanks for your help! My code was a simplified version for here. Your solution works well. But if I include that in my code it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The names you used for your variables are a bit confusing because they are all very similar but I believe I got what you were hoping to achieve:

```
let click = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');
let messageAllClass = document.querySelectorAll('.messageAllClass');

// as previously mention in the comments it's Elements and not Element as this get's a collection of classes
let messageClass = document.getElementsByClassName('messageClass'); 

let messeageIDuniq = document.getElementById('messageID');

let messageTxtAllClass = "hallo from AllClass";
let messageTxtClass = "hallo from Class";
let messageTxtIDuniq = "hallo from ID, i am unique :-)";

let deleted = "deleted";
let i;


let cls = click.length;

//messageAllClass.innerHTML = messAllClass.textContent + messageTxtAllClass;
//messageClass.innerHTML = messageClass.textContent + messageTxtClass;
messeageIDuniq.innerHTML = messeageIDuniq.textContent + messageTxtIDuniq;

for(let i = 0; i < messageAllClass.length; i++) {
  console.log(messageAllClass[i])
    // you want to add the inner html of that collection
    messageAllClass[i].innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('.messageAllClass')[0].innerHTML;

}

for(let i = 0; i < messageClass.length; i++) {
    // you want to add the inner html of that collection  
    messageClass[i].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('messageClass')[0].innerHTML;   

}

for (let i = 0; i < cls; i++) {
  click[i].onclick = function () {
    messageAllClass.innerHTML = "null";
    messageClass.innerHTML = "null";
    messeageIDuniq.innerHTML = deleted;
    alert("all messages deleted!");
  }
}
```